# Integral $ \int_\sigma^\infty r^2 {e^{-A/r^6}} dr $

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, indefinite-integrals, error-function

Below integral can be calculated by using taylor expansion for the $ e^{-A/r^6} $
term. I want to know how to solve this integral **analytically**?
$$ \int_\sigma^\infty r^2 {e^{-A/r^6}} dr $$

*Hint: I think part of the answer contains error function.*

Comment: This integral does not converge for any $A\in\mathbb{R}$. I don't know what you expect for an answer.

Comment: Is it possible that you made a typo when writing the integral?

Comment: Did you perhaps mean $e^{-Ar^6}$?

Comment: I'm completely sure about the integral, the original integral is $ \int_\sigma^\infty r^2 ({1-{e^{-A/r^6}}}) dr $ , which I turn it into two integrals...

Comment: Writing a convergent integral as the difference of two divergent integrals.  Not very heplful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral
$$
\int_\sigma^\infty r^2 {e^{-A/r^6}} \;dr, \qquad A>0
$$
diverges.  Indeed, $r^2 {e^{-A/r^6}} \to +\infty$ as $r \to +\infty$.

Using Maple, I have an antiderivative:

$$
\int r^2 {e^{-A/r^6}}\;dr = \frac{\sqrt{A\pi}}{3}\;\text{erf}\left(\frac{\sqrt{A}}{r^3}\right)+\frac{r^3}{3}\;\exp\left(\frac{-A}{r^6}\right)
$$

---

**added**
A step-by-step version of the antiderivative.

Substutute $y=\sqrt{A}/r^3$
$$
\int r^2 e^{-A/r^6} dr = \frac{-\sqrt{A}}{3}\int \frac{e^{-y^2}}{y^2}\;dy
$$
Then integrate by parts for this one
$$
\frac{-\sqrt{A}}{3}\int \frac{e^{-y^2}}{y^2}\;dy =
\frac{\sqrt{A} e^{-y^2}}{3y} +\frac{2\sqrt{A}}{3} \int e^{-y^2}\;dy
$$

This integral can be recognized using the erf function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I reach the same answer with Wolfram Alpha but I want step by step solution because I can't figure out where error function phrase came from.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I see from the comments that you are actually trying to compute the integral
$$\int_\sigma ^\infty dr\, r^2\left( 1-e^{-A/r^6}\right)$$
Instead of splitting it into 2 divergent integrals, you can expand the exponential into its power series
to obtain
$$\int_\sigma ^\infty dr\,r^2\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1)^{n+1} \frac{(A/r^6)^n}{n!}  $$Switching sum and integral, we obtain
$$\sum_{n\ge 1}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{A^n}{n!}\int_\sigma^\infty dr\, r^{2-6n}$$
Integrating, your final result can be expressed as
$$\frac{\sigma^3}{3}\sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n-1} \frac{\left(A/\sigma^6\right)^n}{n!}$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually I solved this problem with Taylor expansion, but I needed analytical answer which GEdgar answered it.